# Render a partial that uses helper methods to determine view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, refactoring, helper, partials

**What Currently Works:**

In my BookingsController#Index method, I have this

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    if @user.user_type == 'host'
      @bookings = Booking.where(host_id:@user.id, status: "#{params[:status]}")
    else @user.user_type == 'cleaner'
      @bookings = Booking.where(cleaner_id:@user.id, status: "#{params[:status]}")
    end
  end
```

This sets the current user and determines which `@bookings` to display depending on the user_id and params.

In the views, in my `index.html.erb` file, I render bookings `<%= render @bookings %>` which i defined in the `booking#index`. I have a `_booking.html.erb` partial that gets rendered... Inside the `_booking.html.erb` partial, I am able to successfully return booking details , like this for instance,

```
<div id='booking-time'><b>Unit Name:</b> <%= booking.unit.name %></div>
```

will return the unit name. it recognizes the local variable `booking` and the fields that belong to it.

**I'd Like to Refactor:**

I want to refactor this and render a partial `<%= render 'bookings/booking' %>` in my `index.html.erb` file. This partial will render different helper methods that each route to different partials.

Currently my `_booking.html.erb` file has a bunch of conditional logic that is better suited for a helper... I've tried a bunch of different ways to accomplish this to no avail, usually due to undefined variables..what's an elegant way to accomplish this?

**What I've Tried:**

Here's  a method from my bookings_helper.rb` file:

```
  def incoming_to_cleaner_partial_path(bookings)
    return unless booking.status=='pending' && current_user.user_type =='cleaner' && booking.requested_by_id != current_user.id
      'bookings/booking_requests/incoming_to_cleaner'
  end
```

I added logic to these methods to determine which partials to render.

in my modified `_booking.html.erb` file, I call these methods, I pass them a `@bookings` instance variable param.

```
<%= render incoming_to_cleaner_partial_path(@bookings) %>
```

I've also tried this without params.. Neither work..

lastly, I've tried calling a method `determine_bookings_to_show` inside the helper methods. This method contains the same logic from the controller...

```
def incoming_to_cleaner_partial_path
    determine_bookings_to_show
    return unless booking.status=='pending' && current_user.user_type =='cleaner' && booking.requested_by_id != current_user.id
      'bookings/booking_requests/incoming_to_cleaner'
  end

private

def determine_bookings_to_show
    @user = current_user
    if @user.user_type == 'host'
      @bookings = Booking.where(host_id:@user.id, status: "#{params[:status]}")
    else @user.user_type == 'cleaner'
      @bookings = Booking.where(cleaner_id:@user.id, status: "#{params[:status]}")
    end
  end
```

My main issue is i'm having scope troubles with these partials...

Comment: "I've tried a bunch of different ways .." can you show some of the ways you've tried please?

Comment: I updated my post with what i've tried.... didn't want to make the post more confusing than it had to be; incase my solutions were completely misguided.

Answer (score 1):

> .. in my index [I want to] render different partials [depending on attributes of the booking] ..

I have used `render(locals:)` for this in the past.

```rb
# index.html.erb
@bookings.each do |b|
  render_booking(b)
end

# bookings_helper.rb
def render_booking(booking)
  if booking.status == 'pending'
    render partial: 'path/to/bookings/_pending', locals: { booking: booking }
  elsif booking.foobar?
    render partial: 'path/to/bookings/_foobar', locals: { booking: booking }
  else
    # etc.
  end
end
```

Conditionals like this can get complicated, but until then, I think this is an appropriate, practical use of a helper method.

```
# bookings/_pending.html.erb
<h1>Pending Booking <%= booking.id %></h1>
```

You will likely need to pass other `locals:`. I'd avoid using any instance variables in your partials.

Comment: this helper is successful in routing the user to the proper page (Pending or Approved pages), however my initial issue involved what was being displayed on those pages - For example, if I navigate to pending page, there should be an index of 'outgoing pending bookings by user' (helper), and 'incoming pending bookings by user'(also a helper) - I currently have a large html file that handles the logic for displaying these booking types but I want to split that html file up into smaller partials and call them through the helper methods.